# A VB.NET equivalent of C# code for libgit2sharp Credentialsprovider

Tags: c#, vb.net

I'm trying to code against LibGit2Sharp, and I'm falling at the first hurdle

I'm looking at the sample code at
https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/wiki/git-clone

As I need to use credentials I'm looking at the bottom bit of code:

```
var co = new CloneOptions();
co.CredentialsProvider = (_url, _user, _cred) => new UsernamePasswordCredentials { Username = "Username", Password = "Password" };
Repository.Clone("https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp.git", "path/to/repo", co);
```

what has me baffled is

```
co.CredentialsProvider = (_url, _user, _cred) => new UsernamePasswordCredentials { Username = "Username", Password = "Password" };
```

What is the VB.NET equivalent of that code? And ideally I'd like to understand what this does. What does the

```
= (_url, _user, _cred) =>
```

syntax do in C#?

Many thanks

Pino

Comment: That's just an [anonymous function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/lambda-expressions).

Comment: Ok I think I may have it...

Dim oOpt As LibGit2Sharp.CloneOptions
Dim oCred As LibGit2Sharp.UsernamePasswordCredentials

... followed by

oOpt.CredentialsProvider = New LibGit2Sharp.Handlers.CredentialsHandler(Function(_url, _user, _cred) oCred)

Comment: Direct equivalent to your last bit is `Function (_url, _user, _cred) ` (or, in different context, it could be `Sub ...` but here it looks like there's a return value so in VB it's `Function ...`).

Comment: Thank you @Craig that was what I discovered, too. I got it to work now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are too many online converters to mention all of them.
I prefer the converter from Telerik but use the other as a backup.

https://converter.telerik.com/

https://www.carlosag.net/tools/codetranslator/

The code below was converted by Telerik's converter.

```
Dim co = New CloneOptions()
co.CredentialsProvider = Function(_url, _user, _cred) New UsernamePasswordCredentials With {
    .Username = "Username",
    .Password = "Password"
}
Repository.Clone("https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp.git", "path/to/repo", co)
```

If I don't understand a C# code, I will convert it with a converter and that usually helps me understand the C# code.  Sometimes I have to use multiple converters as each one may give a different result.

Answer (score 0):

Along the same lines as Nathan's and Craig's suggestions (thanks all!) I implemented this as follows:

```
    Dim oOpt As LibGit2Sharp.CloneOptions = Nothing
    Dim oCred As LibGit2Sharp.UsernamePasswordCredentials = Nothing

    Try
        oOpt = New LibGit2Sharp.CloneOptions
        oCred = New LibGit2Sharp.UsernamePasswordCredentials
        oCred.Username = "xxxxxxx"
        oCred.Password = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        oOpt.CredentialsProvider = New LibGit2Sharp.Handlers.CredentialsHandler(Function(_url, _user, _cred) oCred)

        Try
            LibGit2Sharp.Repository.Clone("<your repository>", "<your local folder>", oOpt)
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    Catch
    Finally
        If Not oCred Is Nothing Then
            oCred = Nothing
        End If
        If Not oOpt Is Nothing Then
            oOpt = Nothing
        End If
    End Try
```

Job's a good'un

Comment: Glad you figured out your problem.  I learned on VB.NET so sometimes I have problems converting to C#.  It takes time and practice but I am learning the conversions.  You should also mark one of the answers so that everyone knows that your question has been solved.